# Getting user to choose whether or not to exit program

Tags: c, exit

I am trying to end a program by giving the user the option whether to loop back to the start or exit. I've pasted this portion of the program below; 'homenumber' is where it should loop back to and is defined at the start of the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

char option[1];

/*Asks if user wants to exit program*/
printf("Do you want to close the program? [Y/N]: ");
scanf_s("%c",&option,1);

if (option == "N" || option == "n") {
goto homenumber;
}
else if (option == "Y" || option == "y") {
    ;
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

edit: My problem is the program won't let me enter a value for 'option' - it just ends the program no matter what

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Sorry. The program doesn't work, it simply bypasses the scanf_s and ends the program anyway

Comment: Please consult this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The use of `goto` labels is strongly discouraged, as it leads to spaghetti code.

Comment: I'm aware that `goto` isn't the best option but this is a pretty basic code and I'm not going to need it in the future so it'll do the job for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should make `option` a char instead of a character array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    ...

homenumber:

    ...

    char option;

    /* Ask if user wants to exit program */
    printf("Do you want to close the program? [Y/N]: ");
    option = 'Y';
    scanf_s("%c",&option);

    if (option == 'N' || option == 'n') {
        goto homenumber;
    } else
    if (option == 'Y' || option == 'y') {
        ;
    }
```

Note that you should also check the return value of `scanf_s`. I am setting `option` before the call as a quick and dirty solution.  Using `getchar()` instead of `scanf_s` would be simpler and less error prone.

I am not condoning the use of `goto` either, just pointing at the actual issue you have trouble with.

Comment: That still gives me the exact same program with my code. The cursor appears at the end of 'Press any key to continue...' rather than at the end of [Y/N] where it should be.

Comment: Please post the complete code.  Your problem may be hiding somewhere else.